# How can I merge mutiple pdf-files to one?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

import tkinter as tk

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger

import os

mother = tk.Tk()

base_pdf = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('PDF files', '.pdf')], title='Wählen Sie bitte die Basis-PDF-Datei aus')

part_pdf = fd.askopenfilenames(title='Wählen Sie bitte die zugehörigen PDF-Dateien aus')

pdfs = [base_pdf, part_pdf]

x = os.path.basename(base_pdf)

y = x.split('.')[0]


for pdf in mother.splitlist(pdfs):

    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf)
    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
         pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

with open(y + '_Beipack.pdf', 'wb') as target:

        pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
        pdf_writer.write(target)
        print('My PDF Merger', 'Glückwunsch, die PDF-Datei wurde erfolgreich erstellt!')
```

The TypeError i get is a missing argument: 'page'

i tried a lot of things but nothin is workin. I try to merge mutiple pdf-files to one but i cant see my mistake

Comment: Please move the current title to the body of the question and replace it with a short descriptive title, it will increase your chances to get an answer. You can find tips about how to write a question in the help center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

- either use `fd.askopenfilename()` instead of `fd.askopenfilenames()` when selecting `part_pdf` or change `pdfs = [base_pdf, part_pdf]` to `pdfs = [base_pdf, *part_pdf]`
- should create `pdf_writer` before the `for` loop
- should not create `pdf_writer` again inside `with` block

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger
import os

mother = tk.Tk()

base_pdf = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('PDF files', '.pdf')], title='Wählen Sie bitte die Basis-PDF-Datei aus')

part_pdf = fd.askopenfilenames(filetypes=[('PDF files', '.pdf')], title='Wählen Sie bitte die zugehörigen PDF-Dateien aus')

pdfs = [base_pdf, *part_pdf]

x = os.path.basename(base_pdf)

y = x.split('.')[0]

# create the pdf_writer
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

for pdf in mother.splitlist(pdfs):
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf)
    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

with open(y + '_Beipack.pdf', 'wb') as target:
    # removed: pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.write(target)
    print('My PDF Merger', 'Glückwunsch, die PDF-Datei wurde erfolgreich erstellt!')
```